# Can't find boot log information

Tags: boot, logs

From time to time I experience a long delay during my Debian 9 boot with the "Failed to connect to `lvmetad`." message.

After booting, I want to get details about the problem, however can't find any log files with the message.

I seem to try everything `dmesg`, `journalctl`, searched every log file in the `/var/log` directory, but without success.

Please advise on where to find this log information.

Comment: Check: [Ubuntu won't boot because of lvmetad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/745218/ubuntu-wont-boot-because-of-lvmetad) - it might help you out.